# Migrate a project from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10.4;

Tags: delphi

Is there any compatible issue when using TStream.ReadComponent in Delphi 10.4 but the stream data was saved in Delphi 7?
Thanks

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The DFM format is the same as it always has been. But just with added support for Unicode strings in D2009+, etc.  But do be aware that components change over time, so new properties have been added, old properties may have been renamed or dropped, etc.  So that *may* cause DFM streaming issues.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain a list of dropped (changed) properties from standard library?

Comment: no, that information is not documented anywhere

Comment: Ensure the DFM is saved as text, not as binary. Then you may be able to adjust the content easier, and do some search/replace if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple test saving component to stream in Delphi 7 and rebuild the project in Delphi 10.4 (no code change) and marshal back the component from Delphi 7 stream data and it is working.

Below is codes

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Contnrs, StdCtrls;

{$ASSERTIONS ON}

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btGenerate: TButton;
    btRead: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure btGenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btReadClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

  TChildComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FViewID: string;
    FViewCaption: string;
    FSessionID: Cardinal;
    procedure ReadViewCaption(Reader: TReader);
    procedure ReadViewID(Reader: TReader);
    procedure ReadSessionID(Reader: TReader);
    procedure WriteViewCaption(Writer: TWriter);
    procedure WriteViewID(Writer: TWriter);
    procedure WriteSessionID(Writer: TWriter);
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    property ID: string read FViewID write FViewID;
    property Caption: string read FViewCaption write FViewCaption;
    property SessionID: Cardinal read FSessionID write FSessionID;
  end;

  TChildComponentList = class(TComponent)
  private
    FLastFocusViewID: string;
    FList: TObjectList;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetItems(Index: Integer): TChildComponent;
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
    procedure ReadSettings(Reader: TReader);
    procedure WriteSettings(Writer: TWriter);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Add: TChildComponent;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TChildComponent read GetItems; default;
  published
    property LastFocusViewID: string read FLastFocusViewID write FLastFocusViewID;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TChildComponent }

procedure TChildComponent.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  S: TChildComponent;
begin
  if Source is TChildComponent then
  begin
    S := TChildComponent(Source);

    FSessionID := S.SessionID;
    FViewCaption := S.Caption;
    FViewID := S.ID;
  end
  else
    inherited Assign(Source);
end;

procedure TChildComponent.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineProperty('SessionID', ReadSessionID, WriteSessionID, True);
  Filer.DefineProperty('ViewCaption', ReadViewCaption, WriteViewCaption, True);
  Filer.DefineProperty('ViewID', ReadViewID, WriteViewID, True);
end;

procedure TChildComponent.ReadSessionID(Reader: TReader);
begin
  FSessionID := Reader.ReadInteger;
end;

procedure TChildComponent.ReadViewCaption(Reader: TReader);
begin
  FViewCaption := Reader.ReadString;
end;

procedure TChildComponent.ReadViewID(Reader: TReader);
begin
  FViewID := Reader.ReadString;
end;

procedure TChildComponent.WriteSessionID(Writer: TWriter);
begin
  Writer.WriteInteger(FSessionID);
end;

procedure TChildComponent.WriteViewCaption(Writer: TWriter);
begin
  Writer.WriteString(FViewCaption);
end;

procedure TChildComponent.WriteViewID(Writer: TWriter);
begin
  Writer.WriteString(FViewID);
end;

{ TChildComponentList }

function TChildComponentList.Add: TChildComponent;
begin
  Result := TChildComponent.Create(nil);
  FList.Add(Result);
end;

procedure TChildComponentList.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  S: TChildComponentList;
begin
  if Source is TChildComponentList then
  begin
    S := TChildComponentList(Source);

    FLastFocusViewID := S.LastFocusViewID;
  end
  else
    inherited Assign(Source);
end;

constructor TChildComponentList.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FList := TObjectList.Create;
end;

procedure TChildComponentList.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineProperty('ActiveViews', ReadSettings, WriteSettings, True);
end;

destructor TChildComponentList.Destroy;
begin
  Destroying;
  FreeAndNil(FList);
  inherited;
end;

function TChildComponentList.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FList.Count;
end;

function TChildComponentList.GetItems(Index: Integer): TChildComponent;
begin
  Result := FList[Index] as TChildComponent;
end;

procedure TChildComponentList.ReadSettings(Reader: TReader);
var
  PActiveView: TComponent;
begin
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  try
    FList.Clear;
    while not Reader.EndOfList do
    begin
      PActiveView := Reader.ReadComponent(nil);
      FList.Add(PActiveView);
    end;
  finally
    Reader.ReadListEnd;
  end;
end;

procedure TChildComponentList.WriteSettings(Writer: TWriter);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Writer.WriteListBegin;
  for I := 0 to FList.Count - 1 do
    Writer.WriteComponent(TComponent(FList[I]));
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.btGenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TChildComponent;
  List: TChildComponentList;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Save to file: TChildComponentList.bin');

  List := TChildComponentList.Create(nil);
  List.LastFocusViewID := '2';

  Item := List.Add;
  Item.ID := '1';
  Item.Caption := 'TChildComponent1';
  Item.SessionID := 100;

  Item := List.Add;
  Item.ID := '2';
  Item.Caption := 'TChildComponent2';
  Item.SessionID := 1;

  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream.WriteComponent(List);

  Stream.Position := 0;
  Stream.SaveToFile('TChildComponentList.bin');

  Stream.Free;
  List.Free;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Done - OK');
end;

procedure TForm1.btReadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TChildComponent;
  List: TChildComponentList;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Load from file: TChildComponentList.bin');

  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream.LoadFromFile('TChildComponentList.bin');

  Stream.Position := 0;
  List := Stream.ReadComponent(nil) as TChildComponentList;

  Assert(List <> nil);
  Assert(List.Count = 2);
  Assert(List.LastFocusViewID = '2');

  Item := List[0];
  Assert(Item.ID = '1');
  Assert(Item.Caption = 'TChildComponent1');
  Assert(Item.SessionID = 100);

  Item := List[1];
  Assert(Item.ID = '2');
  Assert(Item.Caption = 'TChildComponent2');
  Assert(Item.SessionID = 1);

  Memo1.Lines.Add('List.LastFocusViewID=' + List.LastFocusViewID);

  Stream.Free;
  List.Free;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Done - OK');
end;

initialization
  RegisterClasses([TChildComponent, TChildComponentList]);

end.
```